# python selenium run in windows scheduler cannot locate element

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pyinstaller, windows-task-scheduler

an exe file packaged with pyinstaller execute normally with double click,but when i config it in Windows scheduler, and then start the mission, it comes an exception: cannot locate element.
the line of code is:
`driver.find_element_by_xpath('......').click()`
whats wrong was that?

the element shoud be located and trigger the click event

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.